# Adding arrays to a Queue in Java (pointer issue?)

Tags: java, arrays, linked-list, queue, processing

I'm reading a sensor and want to get an average over an amount of messages, so i'm summing them, and i'm using a queue to remove the first measurement from the sum when a new measurement is added.

The problem is that the queue is not responding to array's as I expected, it somehow acts like a pointer, so when the original value is updated, the history is also changed with it.

```
import java.util.Queue;
Queue<int[]> q = new LinkedList();
int[] t = new int[1];
int len = 3;
void setup() 
{
  for(int i=0;i<len;i++){
    t[0]=len-i;
    q.add(t);
  }
  for(int i=0;i<len;i++){
    print(q.remove()[0]);print(';');
  }
}
```

Result of this code is:
`1;1;1;`

While expected result is:
`3;2;1;`

The question is, how do i properly add Arrays to Queues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must instantiate the array in each iteration of the for loop, otherwise it's the same reference that will be modified

```
Queue<int[]> q = new LinkedList();
int len = 3;

void setup() {
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        int[] t = new int[1];
        t[0] = 5 - i;
        q.add(t);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        print(q.remove()[0]);
        print(';');
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh okay, so i would have to create a for loop to copy over the data over contained in the original instance as well.
Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, i got it working. It's not as elegant as I imagined, but it works.

Comment: why creating an array of length 1, just create a queue of int directly

Comment: It's an array of 11 in the application, but this wasn't relevant for the question.